# How to convert/desurvey Directional Survey measurements into XYZM points?

Tags: convert, linestring, azimuth, oil-gas, borehole

I have a spreadsheet of Wellbore Drill data and would like to generate an XYZM path (LineString) that connects the surface hole location (SHL) to the bottom hole location (BHL) using the actual path of the drill bit.

I am new to processing this kind of data, so I am seeking guidance on best practice / optimal formulas for conversion.

For example, my spreadsheet contains the following columns:

- MeasuredDepth
- TVD (True Vertical Depth)
- Azimuth
- Inclination
- SurfaceX
- SurfaceY
- HorizontalCRS
- AzimuthReference

where each row represents a measurement while drilling (MWD) for a singular well hole ID. For this example, the SurfaceX and SurfaceY values are unchanging throughout each MWD.

I found [this response](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/13487) which outlines a formula to acquire XYZ points, although I do not have a "Dip" column (is Inclination related?). I imagine my data's "MeasuredDepth" could replace the example formula's "Distance", and "TVD" could replace "Z0".

Is this right?

My end goal is to map the Trajectory in GeoJSON for consumption via 2D Map Client. As such the Z and M will not influence the display, but these values are still important for me to preserve - if possible. Implementation will be in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Inclination" field is almost certainly the "Dip", "MeasuredDepth" would be equivalent to "Distance".
Z0 is probably the elevation of your collar at the surface, not the TVD/True Vertical Depth, as it's a single value.